# am trying to remove data table row row if column value match

Tags: c#

this is my code

```
 int name = rajesh
 data table dt = nothing;

 --------some code---- 

 dt
   .Select("Name='Rajesh'")
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => x.Delete());  

 dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Does your code compiles?

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is in `.ToList()` usage which creates a copy of your collection. So, you won't have no effect of the `dt`, because you try to delete items on cloned collection. Remove `ToList()` an you'll get the result you expected.